# IONIC 3 Recording Audio not working after second recording

Tags: typescript, ionic3

In my application on Ionic 3, I using Media and MediaObject from '@ionic-native/media' to recording audio and this works, the audio is record and played, but after I record one audio the MediaObject.startRecording not returns erros and create the audio file, but when I play the file none audio is playing.
Below this is my .ts Code.

```js
//This is my variables:

  private recording: boolean = false;
  private recordingIco: string = 'assets/img/micico.png';
  private filePath: string;
  private fileName: string;
  private audio: MediaObject;
  audioList: any[] = [];
  public recordingMessage = "Wating for records..."
  public MEDIA_FILES_KEY = 'mediaFiles';
  private audioURI:any;
  private audioFileName:any; 
  private isPlay:boolean = false;
  private audioIco: string = 'assets/img/playico.png';

//This is my constructor:

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: Http, private media: Media, private file: File, public platform: Platform, private mediaCapture: MediaCapture, private storage: Storage, private transfer: FileTransfer) {}

//This is my rec and play functions:

  startRecord() {
    let audioRec:MediaObject;
    this.recordingMessage = "Device is preparing to record...";
    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      this.fileName = 'record'+new Date().getDate()+new Date().getMonth()+new Date().getFullYear()+new Date().getHours()+new Date().getMinutes()+new Date().getSeconds()+'.3gp';
      this.filePath = this.file.dataDirectory + this.fileName;
      this.audio = this.media.create(this.filePath);
    } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      this.fileName = 'record'+new Date().getDate()+new Date().getMonth()+new Date().getFullYear()+new Date().getHours()+new Date().getMinutes()+new Date().getSeconds()+'.3gp';
      this.filePath = this.file.dataDirectory + this.fileName;
      this.audio = this.media.create(this.filePath);
      console.log("recording file = " + this.filePath);
    }
    console.log("start recording...");
    this.audio.startRecord();
    console.log("recording is started...");
    this.recordingMessage = "Device is recording...";
    this.recording = true;
  }

  stopRecord() {
    this.audio.stopRecord();
    console.log("Recording is stoped...");
    this.recordingMessage = "Recording is ended...";
    let data = { filename: this.fileName };
    this.audioList.push(data);
    localStorage.setItem("audiolist", JSON.stringify(this.audioList));
    this.recording = false;
  }

  playAudio() {
    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      this.filePath = this.file.dataDirectory + this.fileName;
      this.audio = this.media.create(this.filePath);
    } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      this.filePath = this.file.dataDirectory + this.fileName;
      this.audio = this.media.create(this.filePath);
    }
    this.audio.play();
    this.audio.setVolume(0.8);
    console.log("The device is playing audio...");
    this.recordingMessage = "Device is playing audio...";
  }
```

Comment: What is your actual question? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: My question is about the recording that is not playing the audio after second recording.
I think the problem is instance of the Media object or bug on plugin, or any others reasons.
Thanks for your react.